# Vertical and horizontal scoll at a time in gridview with infinite scrolling IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, rubiks-cube

How can one enable horizontal and vertical scrolling at same time in a grid view?

If I have a 4x4 grid of thumbnail images, I want to implement swiping in both directions, left/right and top/bottom. Currently I am done with left and right swipe, but if I select the second cell and swipe towards the top, the 2nd row should be scrolled like a Rubik's cube.

Please share if any one have any idea.

Comment: You are asking for a prepackaged solution, which is something you pay for.

Comment: which are available solutions for this problems please share a link if you have

Comment: I don't know any, and it's difficult to implement. I know a fair lot about the available grid view libraries, and none of the ones I know provide that functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been quite a while since your question but as I've been struggling with the same thing I'm gonna answer it for future reference...

Sadly I could not find a good solution anywhere so after a lot of hours of experimenting I came up with this: https://github.com/AlvinNutbeij/DWGridController

It's still a work in progress but very usable for your purpose I'd say!

Comment: lastly something i see wht i actually need , but it need to refine on scrolling , Thanks

Comment: I haven't had much time to imporove it since I posted the answer, but hopefully I will soon. If you have any improvements, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

How have you currently implemented what you have? Your mention of 'cell' makes it sound like you are using a `UITableView`. You won't manage to make one of those scroll in both directions, you'll need to work with a `UIScrollView`.

I suggest you watch "Designing apps with Scroll Views" from [WWDC 2010](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), then "Advanced Scrollview Techniques" from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/). That'll teach you about how you implement tiling and infinite scrolling.

Essentially what you want to do is implement some kind of view recycling yourself, that works like the way UITableView recycles its cells. When things are scrolled off one side of the scroll view, you remove the views for the things that just scrolled off screen and put them in a queue. When things scroll onto the screen, you pull views out of the queue (or create new ones if the queue is empty) and lay those views out in the correct place.

To do the infinite scrolling, you fake it: when your scroll view gets near its edge, you reposition everything inside it, you move the scroll view's content offset to where you've repositioned the views, and then you continue from there: it's all done at once so the user never notices.

The videos will explain these techniques better than I can sum up here: watch those as your first point of call.

Comment: thanks Amy Worrall , i done with infinity scrolling horizontally thats not issue both direction which i means both swipe horizontal and vertically at same time it like design museum app on appstore do you have any idea about how perform horizontal n vertical scrolling at same time on grid ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure where you're getting stuck. Could you edit your question to post your code, and point out which bit of it isn't working?

Comment: Amy , you will understand clearly if you see the app i mentioned here "design museum collection " on app store its a free app , in that the have grid view which containing images , user cans scroll that grid horizontally or vertically both at same grid (with infinite scrolling) n at same time, and i done with single side infinite scrolling means either i can do horizontal scroll or vertical , so i want to know the technique or method to perform both type of scrolling on single grid at same time.